# How are both queries different ? Both are giving same result

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select a.MenuID,a.MenuStructureID,b.MenuName from 
MenuStructure a, Menu b
where b.MenuID=a.MenuID

select a.MenuID,a.MenuStructureID,b.MenuName from 
MenuStructure a
join Menu b  
on b.MenuID=a.MenuID
```

**If both are same which one should i prefer and why?**

Comment: I'm sure someone will answer rhis with higher insight, but generally: the second way is the newer one, and you should stick to it. One advantage is that you cannot forget to use the ON clause, as it will provide an error; while the first one will work without where and return a generally huge cartesian product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For very simple queries, it's hard to justify using `JOIN` instead of `,`.  As you've seen, the two are very similar.  Which is even more obvious if laid out slightly differently...

```
SELECT
  a.MenuID, a.MenuStructureID, b.MenuName
FROM
  MenuStructure a
,
  Menu b  
    WHERE b.MenuID = a.MenuID

SELECT
  a.MenuID, a.MenuStructureID, b.MenuName
FROM
  MenuStructure a
INNER JOIN
  Menu b  
    ON b.MenuID = a.MenuID
```

It *appears* as though it's just substituting `,` with `JOIN` and substituting `WHERE` with `ON`...

As soon as you write more complicated queries, however, it becomes easier to read with `JOIN` notation, and becomes harder to make mistakes in the first place...

***Missing predicates***

For example, both of these are wrong in the same way, but only the `JOIN` notation will give a syntax error *(and be easier to spot visually in the first place)*.

```
SELECT
  a.MenuID, a.MenuStructureID, b.MenuName
FROM
  MenuStructure a
,
  Menu b  
,
  Items i  
    WHERE b.MenuID = a.MenuID

SELECT
  a.MenuID, a.MenuStructureID, b.MenuName
FROM
  MenuStructure a
INNER JOIN
  Menu b  
    ON b.MenuID = a.MenuID
INNER JOIN
  Items i
```

The first query runs fine, it's equivalent to `CROSS JOIN Items i`, which can be expensive to run and a pain to debug.

The second query, however, has a syntax error near `JOIN Items i` due to the lack of predicate `ON i.MenuID = b.MenuID` *(or similar)*.

Such syntax errors are very very helpful in catching typos and other silly mistakes ***early***.

***OUTER JOINs***

It also becomes even clearer when using `OUTER JOIN` compared to using `(+)`

```
SELECT
  a.MenuID, a.MenuStructureID, b.MenuName
FROM
  MenuStructure a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Menu b  
    ON b.MenuID = a.MenuID
```

That's compared to the old notation...

```
SELECT
  a.MenuID, a.MenuStructureID, b.MenuName
FROM
  MenuStructure a, Menu b
WHERE
  b.MenuID=a.MenuID(+)
```

Not only is `OUTER JOIN` easier to read, if you typed the following by mistake, you'd get different results! *(Subtle typos again being legal but with hard to spot consequences.)*

```
SELECT
  a.MenuID, a.MenuStructureID, b.MenuName
FROM
  MenuStructure a, Menu b
WHERE
  a.MenuID=b.MenuID(+)
```

There are even expressions that *can* be written with `OUTER JOIN` that *can not* be written with `,` and `(+)`.  *(I'll leave that for you to research.)*

For that reason, just about every major distribution recommends against using `(+)`...

- if you're not going to use `(+)` you need to use `OUTER JOIN`.
- if you're going to use `OUTER JOIN`, you're not using `,`
- and really REALLY don't mix `,` with `OUTER JOIN`...

One of the main "culprits" for propagating using `,` is Oracle.  It's tutorials and help files are full of `,`.  But even Oracle recommend not using `(+)`!

- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52355

***Conclusion***

Over all `JOIN` syntax is easier to read and more likely to give syntax errors where `,` may give silent failures.

When introducing `OUTER JOIN` that becomes compounded, and even leads to situations that `,` and `(+)` can't handle.

Not to mention that `JOIN` was codified in 1992.  Why would you use a standard that's even older than that!?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the explicit join (bottom version) is easier to read/debug. So if others need to use the same code or you need to review it after a long time that is preferred.

Comment: That is certainly not the reason why you should use join.

Comment: @Hello_my_dog_can_code : Actually, readability and so maintainability is also ***my*** top reason for using `JOIN`.  What is ***your*** top reason?

Comment: It is just a bad habit, as for example the "outer join" version of this syntax is deprecated/discontinued in SQL Server 2008-2012.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to JOIN two tables you can do it in two ways. One using ANSI compliant INNER JOIN and another with old style join

But it is advisable not to use old style join. Here is the reason.

Let us create the following data sets

```
CREATE TABLE item_master(item_id INT, item_description VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE item_sales(item_id INT, sales_date DATETIME, qty INT);
INSERT INTO item_master
SELECT 1,'Samsung' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'LG'; 
INSERT INTO item_sales
SELECT 1,'2015-04-03 12:10:10',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2015-06-11 07:22:00',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2015-06-12 11:00:48',22;
```

If you want to show each item_item description with total quantity that are sold, you can use this code

**Method 1 : INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT item.item_description,SUM(details.qty) AS qty FROM item_master AS item
INNER JOIN item_sales AS details
ON item.item_id=details.item_id
GROUP BY item.item_description;
```

**Method2 : Old style join with WHERE clause**

```
SELECT item.item_description,SUM(details.qty) AS qty FROM item_master AS item
,item_sales AS details
WHERE item.item_id=details.item_id
GROUP BY item.item_description;
```

Both returns the following result

```
item_description qty
 ------------------- ----------
 LG 25
 Samsung 2
```

But what happens if you omit the WHERE condtion in method 2 by mistake

```
SELECT item.item_description,SUM(details.qty) AS qty FROM item_master AS item
,item_sales AS details
GROUP BY item.item_description;
```

The result is

```
item_description qty
 ------------------- ----------
 LG 27
 Samsung 27
```

Which is totally wrong as it leads to cross join

But method 1 will throw error if no JOIN is specified

```
SELECT item.item_description,SUM(details.qty) AS qty FROM item_master AS item
INNER JOIN item_sales AS details
GROUP BY item.item_description;
```

The error is

> ```
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.
> ```

Reference : [SQL SERVER – Why Should You Not to Use Old Style JOIN?](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/10/08/sql-server-why-should-you-not-to-use-old-style-join/)